# antd Switch checked property

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to ask a question about the Swtich component from `antd` the React UI library.

```
<Switch checked={true} />
```

When I set checked property I no longer can change it!
I have looked at the API on the [antd website](https://ant.design/components/switch/) but I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Please also have a look at [my sample code here on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-snyder-gbwxz?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: you cannot change it because you have permanently set it to true.

Answer (score 6):

It is because the component is controlled and the value is always set to `true`.

You can do 2 things here:

1. Update `checked` to `defaultChecked`
2. Add state variable and an `onChange` event. You can also check the working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-archimedes-v26kq?file=/src/App.js:111-336

```
export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
      <Switch checked={checked} onChange={setChecked} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Read more about controlled component here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: The first one worked for me. That was awesome

Answer (score 3):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Switch } from "antd";

export default function App() {
  const [isStatus, setStatus] = useState(false);

  const buttonHandler = () => {
    setStatus((status) => !status);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
      <Switch onChange={buttonHandler} checked={isStatus} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can handle it

```
export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
      <Switch onClick={() => setActive(!active)} checked={active} />
    </div>
  );
}
```